# How to set a specific face's texture color in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, voxels, mesh

First off, let me describe my situation...
So I'm building a voxel engine based on [this](http://alexstv.com/index.php/category/voxel-tutorial) tutorial. I'm using my own texture tilesheet. Most of the tiles have their own color except grass, leaves, and a few others. These specific ones are meant to be colored based on the temperature and humidity of the location.

AlexStv (the author of the tutorial linked above) said the mesh colors array could be set, but I tried that and nothing happened. I probably did it wrong though, not sure. But he also said "you may need a shader that render vertex colors, not sure if the standard shader does that anymore" so that could also be the issue.

So... Do I need a custom shader? If not how do set the face's colors?

EDIT, Note: I just tried a custom shader called UnityVC, it still didn't work so I guess I must be doing the color thing he suggested wrong.

Comment: Sharing your vertex colouring code and shader code snippets would help us diagnose where the problem is.

Comment: @DMGregory That code is already thrown out, I had no faith in it. It completely failed no matter which way I could think of doing it. That's why I'm here.